# How to Show specific item from combobox 1 when i choose certain items from another combobox 2

Tags: vb.net, combobox

net and i need help.

In my coding i have 2 combobox so lets assume combobox1 and combobox2

In my combobox1 i have 3 items(1,2,3)
In my combobox2 i have 5 items lets say(1,2,3,4,5)

How do i setup my combobox to show certain items.. let say if i choose 1 from combobox1 then it will show 2,3,4 and will hide 1,5 in combobox2, if i choose 2 from combobox1 then it will show 1,5 and it will hide 2,3,4 for example..

I tried combobox2.item.add but all it did is duplicating items when i choose another item from combobox1 and play it back and forth by choosing different items in combobox1

Example code Below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() = "1" Then
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("2")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("3")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("4")
    ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() = "2" Then
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("1")
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("5")
    Else
        ComboBox4.Items.Add("6")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than telling us a story about your code, why not post the actual code that isnt working?

Comment: I got some questions for you: 1. Is it a WPF, Winform, ASP.NET MCV or Webform application? 2. What have you tried? 3. Can we see your code?

Comment: `i need help`  that can be found here: [help], and here: [ask] and here: [tour]

Comment: What if you choose 3 from combobox1, then what will be displayed in combobox2?

Comment: please mark my answer as answer if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy..

```
Private sub ComboBox1_indexchanged
 combo2.items.clear
 Dim ab() As String = New String() _      {"1", "2", "3"}
 if combo1.text="1" then
 combo2.items.addrange(ab)
```

Comment: I guess OP would like: it will show 2,3,4 in combobox2, when combobox1.text="1", and will show 1,5 in combobox2 ,when combobox1.text="2"...

Comment: edit my codee the way u want and mark it as amswer if it helped

Comment: Sorry, I trid but some medorators rejected my edit. the reason is "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner." , Actually, my modification is based on your thought..   :D  so, please improve your post by yourself..  thanks.

Comment: Hello zack, i did what u just told me to do.. it works but not what i need it because if i choose for example "2" for combobox1, it will show the items for ab if i choose first option from the beginning... and it will duplicate if i play it... by choosing different items back and forth from combobox1

Comment: WOW IT WORKS!! THANK YOU!

Comment: please mark the answer as answer if it helped and uovote it

Comment: i have mark it, but i cant upvote it i need 15 reps.. sory T_T